# How $x \ge 8$ represents every value of $x \ge 5$?

Tags: inequality

I'm new to quadratic inequalities. I was trying to solve this following problem -

> $$x^2 - 13x + 40 \ge 0 $$
> $$(x-5)(x-8) \ge 0 $$

When we consider both of these expressions positive -

$$(x-5) \ge 0$$ and $$(x-8) \ge 0 $$
we get $x \ge 5$ and $x \ge 8$

And I was taught to simplify this as $x \ge 8$. I know this expression also indicates that $x$ is ***greater than*** $5$, but it doesn't show that $x$ can be ***equal to*** $5$. Or when simplifying expressions with ***greater than or equal to*** sign, does ***equal to*** doesn't have much significance here.

Comment: If $x\ge 5$ **and** $x\ge 8$, then $x$ **cannot** be equal to $5$, since it is required to be at least $8$. The point is that any real number that satisfies the second inequality automatically satisfies the first, so the first is superfluous.

Comment: I think an important point you might be missing is that "or equal to" doesn't mean that actually has to be a possibility! For example, we can say that for all real numbers $x$, $x^2 \geq -1$ is a true statement, even though it actually can't be less than $0$ so it will never equal $-1$. There's actually a special distinction for "or equal to" inequalities that actually *can* be equal, they're called **sharp inequalities**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The blue region is is x ≥ 5

[image]

The red region is x ≥ 8

As you are solving the inequality with **AND** , it refers to the intersection of both the areas

[image]

This is the reasoning behind why you were taught to simplify x≥5 **and** x≥8 as x≥8

Comment: I have been specific to your doubt. I know that you missed the solution x ≤ 5 or maybe you didn't mention it, I just answered your "why".

Comment: I didn’t mention x ≤ 5 intentionally. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not,

$$x\ge 5\land x\ge 8\iff x\ge 8$$ is a true expression.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the case when $x-5\le 0$ AND $x-8\le 0$. This yield a solution $x\le 5$. So the final answer is $x\ge 8$ OR $x\le 5$. Equivalent $$x\in(-\infty,5]\cup[8,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

Your question is the wrong way round.

$x\ge 5$ includes every instance of $x\ge 8$, so if you want both to be true you only have to check $x\ge 8$. Then $x\ge 5$ is automatically satisfied as well.